# Do all quarkus extensions have to be the same version?

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

Let's say I have a pom.xml like

```
<properties>
  <quarkus-plugin.version>2.13.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.13.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-jackson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Do all quarkus extensions have to be 2.13.3.FINAL version? Or would it be possible to have something like the code below? This would allow one extension to be a different version, while all other extensions default to the `quarkus.platform.version`.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-redis-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.16.4.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster on several levels. Don't do it, even if it perhaps seems to work.

Comment: @Ladicek could you explain more why it would be a recipe for disaster? 
Also, you are saying that all quarkus extensions should be based on the same version correct? This specific case didn't work, but I couldn't find any documentation that says quarkus extensions have to be the same version.

Comment: Quarkus is not a set of libraries, it is a platform. All extensions depend on Quarkus core, and they may depend on each other (for example, most extensions will depend in one way or another on ArC, the CDI implementation in Quarkus). The platform is built and tested and meant to be used as a single cohesive whole. I don't think anyone has ever considered the option to rip out one piece of the platform and replace it with a transplant of an equivalent piece from a different version of the platform, which is probably why you can't find anything about that in the documentation.